# Eclipse file explorer not working with real device

Tags: android, eclipse, file, adb, explorer

I can use the file explorer fine with the emulator, but when I try to open directories with an actual device, it is unable to open the directory.

I have selected my device under the Devices tab, and I can see the directories under the file explorer tab.

If I try to used adb shell on the cmd line, I can see the directories but when I try to open them I get: "opendir failed, Permission denied"

the permissions on the directory are drwxrwx--x

I feel like there might be some permission setting on the device that I am overlooking, any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access most of the filesystem on production devices, except perhaps on rooted ones, by any means, let alone DDMS' file manager.

For your own app, you can use **`adb shell run-as`** to copy a file to external storage, then copy it off from there using DDMS' file manager, or **`adb pull`**, or just using your normal desktop OS to copy from the mounted storage.